# How to install other Text To Speech engines on android things?

Tags: android, raspberry-pi, text-to-speech, raspberry-pi3, android-things

I want to install E-Speak Text To Speech(TTS) engine android app on the android things running on raspberry pi hardware. How can we add other TTS engines so that we can use them in our main project. 
We can use google TTS but what is the way to install other TTS engines like E-Speak,Eloquence and Vocalizer etc on Android things?

eg.
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.googlecode.eyesfree.espeak&hl=en

Comment: This link shows how a basic TTS object is created and Goole TTS is downloaded http://androidthings.blogspot.in/2012/01/android-text-to-speech-tts-basics.html